# Laravel - Error on Artisan optimize

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, webserver

I am trying to run the following commands using ssh in the 
vhost folder

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```

But I am getting the following error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  'continue' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context
```

How I should go about it.
As the Application was running fine on localhost. but while running on webserver I am getting the error like

```
file_put_contents(E:\wamp\www\test\server-migrate\megashopping_dk_files\storage\framework\views/30b1ec2c5a454e2084c2f1b072c9370d42561717.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Seems like your folder/file has not the correct rights to write this file...

Comment: which folder permission I need to change. is it `storage` and should I set it to 777

Comment: I have already run this command `chmod -R guo+w storage`. But still I am getting the error.

Comment: have you checked the permissions if the command worked?

Comment: it doesn't show any error after running that command. means it's ok. detail error is like this on `php artisan config:cache` - `╰─➤  php artisan cache:clear                                              255 ↵
PHP Fatal error:  'continue' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in /var/www/c                                                                                                 lients/client1/web1/web/megashopping_dk_files/app/Console/Commands/RetailerUpdat                                                                                                 e.php on line 231`

Comment: what php version do you use? maybe you have 5.x on local and 7 on the server...?

Comment: php7 on both local and server

Comment: BTW - which files I can safely delete, which be recreated by laravel?

Comment: you should keep: storage/logs, storage/framework, storage/app - u can delete everything inside this folders

Comment: You sure you don't have a random `continue` somewhere in your code where it shouldn't be?

Comment: I think I should delete this and then check the result.

Comment: I am not sure as the code is not mine. But again it shouldn't be. Reason for is this is that I have run this commands on the same app on localhost without any issue and it is running fine on localhost.

Comment: Try clearing your cache. What its trying to do is uploading some view generated by laravel

Comment: you sure your command line php is also php7? it differs sometimes from the php on your webserver.

Comment: ok problem solved. I have commented the code indicated in the error `RetailerUpdate.php` and then I was able to run the command. now it's working fine. thank you all, who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this error. Looks Like It's Permission Problem. Run this command at `/var/www`.
**In case of Ubuntu/Debian:**

```
chown -R www-data:www-data test
```

**In case of CentOS:**

```
chown -R apache:apache test
```

Hope this helps!